# Create new webdriver instance with different browsers in protractor5.1

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I have some automation scripts with following initialization of new browser instances in protractor:

```
var driver = new protractor.Builder().usingServer(selenium_adress).withCapabilities(caps).build();

newBrowser = protractor.wrapDriver(driver);
```

In this way, it was possible to have one firefox browser, one chrome browser and e.g. one IE browser and work with them parallely.

Since Protractor 5, there is no wrapDriver function available anymore, we have to use browser.forkNewDriverInstance() function. 
But, how can I create a new browser instance with different Browser Types now?

Any Idea?

Thx!

Regards,
Waldemar

Comment: Is your code interacting between the different browser instances that you create? If not, you can use the multicapabilities option with an array of capabilities for different browsers in the config file.

Comment: That is the problem, i want to interact between the different browsers. It was possible with the browser instance, created by wrapDriver.